# Как запустить функцию после "return" на ASP.NET MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Контроллер при запросе выдаёт файл.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File(FilePath, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, "File.txt");
}
```

Мне нужно, как только файл отдастся(именно отдастся весь, а не обрыв в сети произойдёт)- удалить его, но так как ActionResult возвращает значение после return -я не могу выполнить другой метод после этого.
Как запустить мeтод, как только сработал ActionResult?

Comment: Не силен в MVC, но первое, что приходит на ум - это вернуть копию результата. 
Т.е. объявить "ActionResult temp;" внутри метода, после чего получить содержимое файла в temp, удалить файл и вернуть temp.

Comment: Ты можешь передать скачать в массив байт, удалить файл и передать массив байт http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult

Comment: Так же можно попробовать использовать try finaly

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте заголовок вопроса. У вас вопрос про файлы, а не про return.

Answer (score 2):

По мотивам
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Так же можно использовать временные файлы по примеру

[How do I automatically delete tempfiles in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400140/how-do-i-automatically-delete-tempfiles-in-c/25411729#25411729)

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.GetTempFileName(),
       FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None,
       4096, FileOptions.RandomAccess | FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    // temp file exists
}
```

Так же можно посмотреть здесь [API for temp file](http://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/6561756.flat)

Comment: @"Serginio" впринципи да, но теоретически есть шанс, что скачивая большой файл мы вгрузим его в память и удалим сам файл, а потом с памяти будем отдавать.....а потом инет пропадёт....а файла то уже нет, что б повторить процедуру- это впринципи смущает.

Comment: Тогда темповые файлы, которые будут удаляться при закрытие при испльзовании using

Comment: Try catch finaly

Comment: То есть в catch восстанавливать файл

Comment: Еще один вариант, это от клиента сообщить об доставке файла и удалять на сервере

Comment: я впринципи такой вариант сейчас делаю(клиент уведомляет, что скачал)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы убедиться, что файл был получен получателем полностью - достаточно дождаться прихода пакета ACK на последний из отправленных байт. Но, насколько мне известно, существующие драйвера TCP не позволяют получить эту информацию.

Кроме того, драйвер HTTP.SYS и веб-сервер IIS скрывают реальный TCP-сокет.

Поэтому выходом могло бы быть размещение отдельного самописного HTTP-сервера на отдельном порту, который бы не использовал постоянные соединения - в таком случае файл можно удалять после окончания входящего потока.

---

Но тут есть еще одна проблема. Дело в том, что любой прокси-сервер будет рад закешировать результат запроса - и забыть отдать клиенту. Да и браузеры бывают рады начудить с протоколом (например, забыть закрыть соединение)...

Поэтому вам надо решить, что важнее: удалить файл или доставить его пользователю.

Во втором случае лучше всего удалять файл по таймеру. Например, через месяц после первого скачивания.

В первом случае можно взять за основу вот этот код: [FilePathResult.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FilePathResult.cs) - и добавить там удаление файла после полной отправки.